# How to use pandas apply function on all columns of some rows of data frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a `dataframe`. I want to replace values of all columns of some rows to a default value. Is there a way to do this via `pandas apply` function

Here is the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
temp=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'b':[2,3,4,5,6,7],'c':['p','q','r','s','t','u']})
mylist=['p','t']
```

How to replace values in columns `a` and `b`to default value 0,where value of column `c` is in `mylist`

Is there a way to do this using pandas functionality,avoiding for loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) to create a boolean mask and use `loc` to set the rows that meet the condition to the desired new value:

```
In [37]:
temp.loc[temp['c'].isin(mylist),['a','b']] = 0
temp

Out[37]:
   a  b  c
0  0  0  p
1  2  3  q
2  3  4  r
3  4  5  s
4  0  0  t
5  6  7  u
```

result of the inner `isin`:

```
In [38]:
temp['c'].isin(mylist)

Out[38]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: c, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks @EdChum. But does this work efficiently with around 500 columns and 1mn rows

Comment: it should do, essentially you're using the boolean mask to select the rows of interest, you pass a list of columns you want to replace the values for, this will be much faster than using `apply`

Answer (score 1):

NumPy based method would be to use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to get such a mask and use it like so -

```
mask = np.in1d(temp.c,mylist)
temp.ix[mask,temp.columns!='c'] = 0
```

This will replace in all columns except `'c'`. If you are looking to replace in specific columns, say `'a'` and `'b'`, edit the last line to -

```
temp.ix[mask,['a','b']] = 0
```