# create new pandas dataframe column based on if-else condition with a lookup

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a pandas dataframe and I need to create a new column based on an if-else condition. This question already came up here multiple times (e.g., [Creating a new column based on if-elif-else condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702342/creating-a-new-column-based-on-if-elif-else-condition)).

However, I cannot apply the proposed solution, since I also need to look up values in a list in order to check the condition. I cannot do this with the proposed solution, because I am not sure how I can access my lookup-list in the external function. My lookup-list would need to be global, which I want to avoid. I have the feeling there should be a better way to do this.

Consider the following dataframe `df`:

```
letters
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

I also have a list which contains lookup values:

```
lookup = [C,D]
```

Now, I want to create a new column in my dataframe which contains `1` if the respective value is contained in `lookup` and `0` if the values is not in `lookup`.

The typical approach would be:

```
df.apply(helper, axis=1)

def helper(row):
  if(row['letters'].isin(lookup)):
     row['result'] = 1
  else:
     row['result'] = 0
```

However, I do not know how I can access `lookup` in `helper()` without making it global.

The result should look like this:

```
letters    result
A          0
B          0
C          1
D          1
E          0
F          0
```

Comment: This is very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499890/how-to-use-pandas-apply-function-on-all-columns-of-some-rows-of-data-frame you just need to do `df.loc[df['letters'].isin(lookup),'result'] = 1`

Comment: Or more complete is `df['result'] = np.where(df['letters'].isin(lookup), 1, 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this question is very similar to the question: [How to use pandas apply function on all columns of some rows of data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499890/how-to-use-pandas-apply-function-on-all-columns-of-some-rows-of-data-frame)

I think here it's worth showing a couple methods, on a single line using `np.where` with a boolean mask generated from `isin`, `isin` will return a boolean Series where any rows contain any matches in your list:

```
In [71]:
lookup = ['C','D']
df['result'] = np.where(df['letters'].isin(lookup), 1, 0)
df

Out[71]:
  letters  result
0       A       0
1       B       0
2       C       1
3       D       1
4       E       0
5       F       0
```

here using 2 `loc` statements and using `~` to invert the mask:

```
In [72]:
df.loc[df['letters'].isin(lookup),'result'] = 1
df.loc[~df['letters'].isin(lookup),'result'] = 0
df

Out[72]:
  letters  result
0       A       0
1       B       0
2       C       1
3       D       1
4       E       0
5       F       0
```