# Create new column in pandas dataframe based on if/elif/and functions

Tags: python-3.x, sklearn-pandas

I have searched for my exact issue to no avail. These two threads [Creating a new column based on if-elif-else condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702342/creating-a-new-column-based-on-if-elif-else-condition) and 
[create new pandas dataframe column based on if-else condition with a lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501685/create-new-pandas-dataframe-column-based-on-if-else-condition-with-a-lookup?noredirect=1&lq=1) guided my code though my code fails to execute.

Issues: I have a dataframe which I have example-reproduced below. Region attribute has two values only - a or b (or could have more), same for year, though region a could have both years etc. What I want to do is create a new column, "dollars", and look up the value for region, and if it is region "a" AND year is e.g 2006, takes sales in that row, and multiply with **rate for that year** and append value in new column - dollars. I am beginner and below is what I have so far - via function - and obviously executing the .apply function returns a **ValueError:** ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0'). I am particularly interested in a more efficient implementation as the dataframe is rather large and would love to optimize computational efficiency.

```
import pandas as np

rate_2006, rate_2007 = 100, 200


c = {
'region': ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b"],
'year': [2006, 2007, 2007, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2006, 2007],
'sales': [500, 100, 2990, 15, 5000, 2000, 150, 300, 250, 1005, 600]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(c)
df1

def new_col(row): 
    if df1["region"] == "a" and df1["year"] == 2006:
        nc = row["sales"] * rate_2006
    elif df1["region"] == "a" and df1["year"] == 2007:
        nc = row["sales"] * rate_2007
    elif df1["region"] == "b" and df1["year"] == 2006:
        nc = row["sales"] * rate_2006
    else:
        nc = row["sales"] * rate_2007
    return nc

df1["Dollars"] = df1.apply(new_col, axis=1)
df1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue maybe due to the way you are using it. I don't know if it will help you. but I have re written the code as per my knowledge that is working.

```
import pandas as pd

rate_2006, rate_2007 = 100, 200


c = {
'region': ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b"],
'year': [2006, 2007, 2007, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2006, 2007],
'sales': [500, 100, 2990, 15, 5000, 2000, 150, 300, 250, 1005, 600]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(c)
print(df1)

def new_col(value): 
    if df1.loc[value,"region"] == "a" and df1.loc[value,"year"] == 2006:
        df1.loc[value,"Dollars"] = df1.loc[value,"sales"] * rate_2006
    elif df1.loc[value,"region"] == "a" and df1.loc[value,"year"] == 2007:
        df1.loc[value,"Dollars"] = df1.loc[value,"sales"] * rate_2007
    elif df1.loc[value,"region"] == "b" and df1.loc[value,"year"] == 2006:
        df1.loc[value,"Dollars"] = df1.loc[value,"sales"] * rate_2006
    else:
        df1.loc[value,"Dollars"] = df1.loc[value,"sales"] * rate_2007

for value in range(len(df1)):
    new_col(value)
```

Comment: your implementation works on the example data set and provides what I want.  I am still running it on my huge data and not sure when it will complete :-). Like I mentioned I know there is probably an efficient approach than my method, so will keep looking.

Comment: There are definitely other efficient methods available. But you can at least start working with this code and can replace this part when you find a better approach.